# How to create a user manipulable grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an [application](https://github.com/digitalbricklayer/workbench) in which the user is able to create a grid to show the results of a constraint model solution.

The user can create columns and rows in the grid and then assign data processed from the model solution into the grid.

I've been attempting to get the WPF `DataGrid` to work in my scenario. I've manageed to get the columns to work ok. But I am stuck with the rows. `DataGrid` I believe uses reflection to read the column data from the grid data.

Is there any way to supply the row data through an interface instead? Any suggestions welcome, including any that don't use `DataGrid`.

Comment: What about just using a Grid and manipulating the ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions in code-behind?

Comment: Good idea. Will take a look at the row definition class to see what I can do with it.